# ProfileBase Create method return returning null

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using the aspnet_Profile table , it runs locally but when I push it to dev environment and run it there `ProfileBase.Create(user.Username)` returns a null value.

```
var user = Membership.GetUser(Username);
```

is not null and returns a user ,so I'm not sure why a null value is being return for `ProfileBase.Create`.

Any ideas?

---

```
var user = Membership.GetUser(Username);
var ext_user= ProfileBase.Create(user.UserName) as UserProfile;
ext_user.Name = Name;
ext_user.Save();
```

---

```
public class UserProfile : ProfileBase
    {
        public static UserProfile GetUserProfile(string UserName)
        {
            return Create(UserName) as UserProfile;
        }

        public string NameExtended
        {
            get { return base["NameExtended"] as string; }
            set { base["NameExtended"] = value; }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved ,silly mistake on my part. The inherit attribute was not set in my environment .config file.

Answer (score 2):

Fabii is correct with the marked answer, but I didn't initially understand what the answer was until resolving this issue myself.  For the record, you need to do something similar in your config file in which your inherits statement points to your class that is inheriting from ProfileBase:

```
<profile defaultProvider="DefaultProfileProvider" inherits="YourNamespace.YourClass">
```